# What collation can be used to sort all lowercase letters first in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

I am using MarkLogic `8.0-6.3`

I have to sort strings where lowercase letters should be sorted at first.

for example:

```
('a', 'A', 'b', 'B') should be sorted like ('a', 'b', 'A', 'B')
```

Default code-point collation will sort lowercase letters at last.

**Update:**

Output with collation `http://marklogic.com/collation//CL`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can achieve what you want with collations.

You could use the `SI` `<strength>` attribute: `http://marklogic.com/collation//SI`

```
for $i in ("a", "A", "b", "B")
order by $i descending collation "http://marklogic.com/collation//SI"
return $i
```

But that would return `('b', 'a', 'B', 'A')`

Instead of collation, could test whether the value is equal to it's `fn:lower-case()` value, and sort by that boolean value:

```
for $i in ("a", "A", "b", "B")
order by $i eq lower-case($i) descending
return $i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http://marklogic.com/collation//CL`. Documentation on this can be found in the search-dev guide, in the section [Attribute Portion of the Collation URI](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/encodings_collations#id_30273). It can also be useful to look at a random string index in the Admin UI. There is a Collation Builder utility (small button behind the collation setting), which can help you click together the collation you need.

HTH!

Comment: I have tried this one `http://marklogic.com/collation//CL` as well, but I am getting the output as ("a", "A", "b", "B").
I have attached the screenshot of the output.